# Speed up build to debug in Visual Studio using Umbraco

Tags: c#, visual-studio, umbraco

I have a Microsoft Visual Studio solution/web site that includes several other project dll's within the bin folder.  When I make changes to other projects and wish to only update the dll and start debugging, I have to sit for a minute or two while the '/App_Code/' folder is built.

Is there anyway to update the dll's and start debugging without having to rebuild the entire solution?

Answer (score 1):

Practically, no.

When changes to .dll's are detected in the bin directory within an asp.net application it will always restart. Similarly when using the *special* App_Code directory changes to files will trigger a recompilation of the files in turn restarting the application.

If you want to debug without recompiling the code, this can be achieved by running the application in a local IIS instance and using **Debug** > **Attach to Process** > **w3wp.exe** *(Show processes from all users)*.